# How can users sort multiple pages?

Tags: sort

I'm using the following code to display a list of properties on multiple pages. I would like to give users the option of sorting the results by custom fields (perhaps city, or property name, or price). I've tried add_query_arg without success. Does anyone have any suggestions? I would truly appreciate a code example as I'm fairly new to PHP. Thank you so much.

```
                <?php
                $wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'key' => 'listing_status',
                            'value' => array('Active', 'In Contract'),
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => 'listing_type',
                            'value' => 'For Lease'
                        )
                    ),

                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'orderby' => 'title',
                    'order' => 'ASC'

                ));

                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : -1;

                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                <p>Sort by: <a href="<?php echo str_replace(('?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']), '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'/?sort=name'; ?>">Property Name</a> | <a href="<?php echo str_replace(('?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']), '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'/?sort=type'; ?>">Property Type</a>

                <?php if($_GET['sort'] == 'name') $wp_query = new WP_Query(array( 'meta_query' => array( 'relation' => 'AND', array( 'key' => 'listing_status', 'value' => array('Active', 'In Contract'), ), array( 'key' => 'listing_type', 'value' => 'For Sale' ) ), 'paged' => $paged, 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'meta_key' => 'property_name', 'order' => 'ASC' )); ?>

                <?php if($_GET['sort'] == 'type') $wp_query = new WP_Query(array( 'meta_query' => array( 'relation' => 'AND', array( 'key' => 'listing_status', 'value' => array('Active', 'In Contract'), ), array( 'key' => 'listing_type', 'value' => 'For Sale' ) ), 'paged' => $paged, 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'meta_key' => 'property_type', 'order' => 'ASC' )); ?>
```

Comment: Explain **why** that could solve the problem.